# How to navigate on view model field change in Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

In my app I want to send info to server and after receiving successful response I want to pass info to current screen to navigate to another screen.

Here's the flow:

From UI I call `viewModel` to send request to server. In `ViewModel` I have a callback:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CreateAccountViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val cs: CS
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _screen = mutableStateOf("")

    val screen: State<String> = _screen

    fun setScreen(screen: Screen) {
        _screen.value = screen.route
    }

    private val signUpCallback = object : SignUpHandler {
        override fun onSuccess(user: User?, signUpResult: SignUpResult?) {
            setScreen(Screen.VerifyAccountScreen)
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "sign up success")

        }

        override fun onFailure(exception: Exception?) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "sign up failure ")
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I have also `State` responsible for Screen so when response is successful I want to update the state so UI layer (Screen) knows that it should navigate to another screen. My question is: how can I observer State in

```
@Composable
fun CreateAccountScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CreateAccountViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
}
```

Or is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your view model should know nothing about navigation routes. Simple `verificationNeeded` flag will be enough in this case:

```
var verificationNeeded by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set

private val signUpCallback = object : SignUpHandler {
    override fun onSuccess(user: User?, signUpResult: SignUpResult?) {
        verificationNeeded = true
        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "sign up success")
    }

    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception?) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "sign up failure ")
    }
}
```

The best practice is not sharing `navController` outside of the view managing the `NavHost`, and only pass even handlers. It may be useful when you need to test or preview your screen.

Here's how you can navigate when this flag is changed:

```
@Composable
fun CreateAccountScreen(
    onRequestVerification: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: CreateAccountViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    if (viewModel.verificationNeeded) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            onRequestVerification()
        }
    }
}
```

in your navigation managing view:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Screen.CreateAccount
) {
    composable(Screen.CreateAccount) {
        CreateAccountScreen(
            onRequestVerification = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.VerifyAccountScreen)
            }
        )
    }
}
```